# JAVA Ciclo While con dos condiciones

Tags: java, condiciones, while

Estoy intentando hacer un método que controle que el limite esta entre 0 y 100 y quiero controlarlo mediante un ciclo while, pero no me funciona bien.

```
public static int leerLimite(String mensaje){
    //Variable
    int limite = leerEntero(mensaje);

    while (limite > 0 && limite < 100) {            
        limite = leerEntero(mensaje);
    }
    return limite;
}
```

El método al que llamo leer entero, me funciona perfectamente, con ese método solo me aseguro que sea numérico y el parámetro que le paso es el mensaje quiero que vea el usuario.

Creo que la condición lógica esta mal, la otra opción que valora es introducir dos ciclos while, uno para controlar que sea mayor o igual a 0 y otro para controlar que sea menor o igual a 100.

Comment: ¿Que es lo que quieres hacer? El `while` es correcto, pero no se si tiene mucho sentido. ¿Por que necesitas un bucle? Creo que es necesario el código de `leerEntero()` y que expliques mejor la pregunta para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Hola @LuisQuesadaRomero, creo que estarás confundido, la estructura según lo que comentas debería ser if(limite > 0 && limite < 100), si utilizas `while` que es `una estructura de repetición` cuando ingreses por ejemplo 50 la condición seria `true` y el `while `entraría en un bucle infinito hasta que algo modificara el valor de la variable limite a uno fuera de rango por ejemplo 101 lo cual haría que al evaluar nuevamente la condición sea `false` algo que nunca pasaría según tu código y lo que dices que hace `leerEntero`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que quieres hacer es que te vaya preguntando el numero mientras el valor este fuera del rango de 0 a 100.

Si es asi, estas aplicando las condiciones del while al reves, tendrias que hacerlo asi:

```
public static int leerLimite(String mensaje){
    //Variable
    int limite = leerEntero(mensaje);

    while (limite < 0 || limite > 100) {            
        limite = leerEntero(mensaje);
    }
    return limite;
}
```

Asi te ira preguntando mientras el valor sea menor que 0 o mayor que 100 por lo que te devolvera un numero entre 0 y 100.